# Edit UILabel From inside a View Frame

Tags: ios, swift, skview

I have a `UILabel` and a `View` in a `Stack View` inside of the `ViewController` where I have a `GameScene` in that same `View`.

```
'''''''''''''''  <- GameStartViewController
'      L      '
'  '''''''''  '     L = UILabel
'  '   V   '  '     V = View Frame
'  '       '  '
'  '       '  '
'  '       '  '
'  '''''''''  '
'             '
'''''''''''''''
```

I'm trying to update the label which is the score from inside the view but I keep getting

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

Even though it is connected, I can't change color, set text, etc...

Code:

GameScene.swift

```
var gs: GameStartViewController!

override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
    physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self
    self.backgroundColor = UIColor.feelFreeToColor()
    gs.scoreLabel.text = "\(score)" // THIS DOES NOT WORK
}
```

GameStartViewController.swift

```
@IBOutlet weak var selfView: SKView!
@IBOutlet weak var scoreLabel: UILabel!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.feelFreeToColor()
    self.initAdMobBanner()

    let scene: GameScene = GameScene(size: view.bounds.size)
    let skView = selfView
    scene.scaleMode = .AspectFill
    skView.presentScene(scene)

    scoreLabel.layer.addBorder(UIRectEdge.Bottom, color: UIColor.blackColor(), thickness: 3) // THIS WORKS
}
```

I can edit it from the view controller, but can't inside the view frame. How do I access it from inside the view frame?

Comment: Did you mix the namings of the views ? The top code is the View and the bottom is ViewController, right?

Comment: Ah, sorry. Rearranged the file titles...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where are you setting the reference to the parent in your view (in your case to `gs`)?.

Try setting the parent reference in your ViewController like this:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.feelFreeToColor()
    self.initAdMobBanner()

    let scene: GameScene = GameScene(size: view.bounds.size)

    // Notice!
    scene.gs = self

    let skView = selfView
    scene.scaleMode = .AspectFill
    skView.presentScene(scene)

    scoreLabel.layer.addBorder(UIRectEdge.Bottom, color: UIColor.blackColor(), thickness: 3) // THIS WORKS
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What is happening if you try `gs.scoreLabel.text = "Test content"` ?

Where are you setting up and filling the score variable?

Comment: The score variable is a global variable in the initial view controller, it works in the GameStartViewController but not in the view inside the view of the GameStartViewController